# How to restore focus to iframe's parent after user interaction?

Tags: javascript, iframe, html5-video, video.js, lightgallery

I am using the [LightGallery](https://www.lightgalleryjs.com/) lightbox lib to play a video (using [video.js](https://videojs.com/city)) in an iframe. The `esc` key is used to close the `LightGallery` instance. This works fine until the user interacts with the video controls since those are given focus.

How can I restore focus to the `LightGallery` instance after these interactions?

I've been poking around `video.js` and am able to trap these user clicks but so far I haven't been able to figure out what I need to do to return focus so the `esc` key works. I've tried using `postMessage`, `blur` and everything else I could think of and I'm a little lost. Am I asking the wrong question/looking at the wrong thing?

---

Various attempts:

```
player.on('click', function (evt) {
        console.log('iframe window', window.frameElement);
        
        evt.currentTarget.blur();

        window.postMessage("hello", "*")
        // var lg = document.getElementById('vidContainer');
        // var lg = document.getElementsByClassName('lightGallery');
        // console.log('lg', lg);
        // console.log('document', document);
        // lg.focus()
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I  resolved the "focus" issue in what may be a really hacky way but it seems to work to insure that the lightbox close button can always be triggered by the escape key,

1. When the iframe loads, store a reference to the close button in the parent window.

   ```
   let closeBtn

    window.onload = function () {
      closeBtn = parent.document.getElementsByClassName("lg-close lg-icon")[0]
    }
   ```

---

2. Add a click event handler to the `Videojs` instance and use it to reassert focus on the close button after the user has interacted with the video controls. Not great, not accessibility friendly but this is what the client is expecting.

   ```
   player.on('click', function (evt) {
       closeBtn.focus();
   });
   ```

Comment: If you would be using Fancybox, then you could do like this: `player.on('click', function (evt) { Fancybox.getInstance().focus(); });`